# joomla extentions like http://www.cinema.ucla.edu web page

Tags: joomla-extensions

I want to make a web page that in the first page displays a set of roll-over images with specific information like in the following link: http://www.cinema.ucla.edu/

Does anyone knows which joomla extention is this in the specific site?

Answer (score 0):

The website you link to is a Drupal website.

Very Simple Image Gallery might do what you are after though:

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/photos-a-images/galleries/content-photo-gallery/6301